# Where can I find out more information on PISCES?

Tags: delta-green-rpg

I've just got hold of a copy of the new version of Delta Green, and as I'm based in the United Kingdom, I'm really interested in PISCES, the British equivalent of Delta Green in the setting. There's a reasonable amount in the new Delta Green book, but I was wondering whether any of the source books from the older versions of the game had anything more detailed.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure which Delta Green book you have, but the history of PISCES is contained in the sourcebook [Delta Green:Countdown](https://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/99299/Delta-Green-Countdown). That book has close to 20 pages dedicated to the history and structure of PISCES, as well as another 10 pages outlining the important individuals of the organization.

Opening paragraph for the section:

> DELTA GREEN BEGAN AS A TOP-SECRET, BLACK-BUDGET Pentagon operation defending America against paranormal threats. Today it is an illegal conspiracy of dedicated individuals who beg, borrow, and steal what they need for their crusade. All things considered, the 
>    situation could have turned out far worse. Majestic-H, which began as a project to unravel the mysteries of the alien visitors and defend against their incursions, has become the aliens' partner in exploiting humanity. But there are worse things than being turned into outcasts or played for fools. Take the example of PISCES, Britain's Paranormal Intelligence Section for Counter-intelligence, Espionage and Sabotage.

Answer (score -2):

The three issues of The Black Seal also contain PISCES information.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more? Perhaps the specific location (page numbers maybe) on the source and a short summary of what kind of information can be found